# Drupal View is missing some fields

Tags: php, drupal

I'm new to Drupal, so please don't be too hard on me. I don't have any training on it.

So I have a page where there are a list of blogs, inside each blog contains a field for social media links. However when I click on an individual blog which then brings me to its own page, the social media links are gone. How can I add them?

I've attached 2 images. The first one shows the share link. The second one shows the individual blog page **without** the share links.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Depends on the view type. If you are displaying fields then check if links field is added to that view set of fields. If you are displaying nodes then check display options for that content type.

Answer (score 0):

If social media links are stored as a field of your Blog content type, go to *Structure > Content types > Blog > Display fields* and make sure the social media links field is not hidden.